# Embedded PC with Gigabit Ethernet and SD card interface?

Tags: embedded, sd

Where do I find such a module? All of the embedded PC modules I've seen so far have only a slow 10/100 Mbit/s Ethernet interface.

This is for a scanner application. I get incoming data at a rate of 2 MByte/s, which I need to store locally e.g. on an SD card. The whole image is over 10 GByte, which is why I need a fast interface to transfer it to a PC.

Here's one I just found: Technologic Systems [TS-7800](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7800); it even features an user-programmable [FPGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array). There are [other models](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/index.php) available.

Comment: I've used the Technologic Systems boards before-- they're good stuff.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that the SD card is going to be your limiting factor not the network interface.  You better make sure whatever dev board you get is running in 4bit mode and supports 50Mhz SD clock or you have no chance of getting 10MB/sec read/write out of it.  If the SD port is run in 1 bit or SPI mode you'll never get 10MB/sec out of it so the move to gigabit won't do anything.

Comment: How is this on topic?

Comment: I would work out if the system is ever likely to manage more than 100mbps of throughput - a low powered system (especially accessing an SD card) is unlikely to be able to saturate the network connection, so having a Gbit interface would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [RouterBOARD](http://routerboard.com/pricelist.php?started_from_home=1) -- These are custom designed hardware meant to be used with the Linux-based [MikroTik](http://www.mikrotik.com/index.html) router software, but no reason you couldn't put your own software on there. You didn't really say anything at all about your application, so it's hard to give a specific recommendation, but the [RB750G](http://routerboard.com/index.php?showProduct=90) is a good combination of price & power I think. 680MHz CPU, 32MB RAM, with 5 gigabit LAN ports.

Answer (score 1):

[Guruplug Server](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-guruplugdetails.aspx). It has dual Gigabit Ethernet, USB, eSATA, external SD card interface and a bunch of other ports. It runs Linux too.

Guruplug Server Plus will set you back US$130. Mine has already been ordered!

Comment: probably should also mention that the order page is here: http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/c-4-guruplugs.aspx